# Unique constraint error on table column with One to Many relation

Tags: sql

I've these two Openjpa entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "os_wfentry")
public class JPAWorkflowEntry implements WorkflowEntry, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -755511983025049452L;

    @Id
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String workflowName;

    @Column(name = "state")
    private Integer workflowState;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "workflowEntry")
    private final List<JPACurrentStep> currentSteps;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "workflowEntry")
    private final List<JPAHistoryStep> historySteps;
```

... and this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "os_currentstep")
public class JPACurrentStep implements Serializable, Step {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3662582760248954945L;

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "action_Id")
    protected Integer actionId;

    @Column(name = "step_Id")
    protected Integer stepId;

    protected String caller;

    @Column(name = "finish_Date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    protected Date finishDate;

    @Column(name = "start_Date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    protected Date startDate;

    @Column(name = "due_Date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    protected Date dueDate;

    @Column
    protected String owner;

    protected String status;

    @ManyToOne
    protected JPAWorkflowEntry workflowEntry;
```

and when I run my application I've this SQL error:

```
ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "os_wfentry" {stmnt 989537113 ALTER TABLE os_currentstep ADD FOREIGN KEY (workflowentry_id) REFERENCES os_wfentry (id) DEFERRABLE} [code=0, state=42830]
```

On my opinion it's all right, in fact tabels are "linked" by id that is unique, I don't figure out why it gives me this error.

Answer (score 1):

It is trying to setup the foreign key relationship `os_currentstep.workflowentry_id`->`os_wfentry.id` but for this to be valid `os_wfentry.id` must be a valid candidate key which from SQL Server's point of view means it *must* either be the primary key or a non-nullable column covered by a unique constraint - the error is telling you that this is not the case so the foreign key can not be added.

I'm not familiar with Openjpa so I can't tell you how to fix that in its syntax. You need to mark `id` in `os_wfentry` as the primary key for that table (assuming it is) *or* add a unique index covering it.